# Reduce CPU usage in threejs application

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, rendering

I am currently working on a project where I am programming Snake in Threejs (yes I know there are simpler methods). Everything seems to work fine, but when the snake reaches a certain size the CPU usage jumps to 50% or more and the whole browser tab freezes.

Here is the code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timon_dev/j1bhm4fv/24/)
(There is a start/restart button at the end of the page)

```
// Javascript
import * as THREE from "three";
import { gsap } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gsap";

const wh = window.innerHeight,
    gamesize = 25,
    mid = Math.floor(gamesize / 2),
    scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ),
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-0.5, gamesize + 0.5, gamesize + 0.5, -0.5, 1, 100),
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: $("#threejs")[0]}),
    game = {
        snake: {
            body: [],
            length: 0,
            d: "+x"
        },
        food: {},
        running: true
    },
    snakeEvent = new Event("snake");
    
class CreateSnake {
    constructor (x, y, d) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = 0;
        this.d = d;
        this.box = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
            new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
        );
    };
    getCoords () {
        return [this.x, this.y, this.z];
    };
    getDirection () {
        return this.d;
    };
}

class CreateFood {
    constructor () {
        let c = validFoodLocations();
        this.x = c[0];
        this.y = c[1];
        this.z = 0;
        this.box = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000})
        );
    };
    getCoords () {
        return [this.x, this,y, this,z]
    };
}

function init () {
    $("#threejs").trigger("focus");
    game.snake.body.push(new CreateSnake(mid, mid, "+x"));
    game.snake.body[0].box.position.set(mid, mid, 0);
    addFood();
    scene.add(light, game.snake.body[0].box);
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x1C3144);
    camera.position.setZ(10);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(1/1);
    renderer.setSize(wh, wh);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    addEventListener("resize", () => {renderer.setSize(window.innerHeight, window.innerHeight);});
    addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
    game.gameloop = setInterval(gameloop, 100);
    animate();
};

addEventListener("snake", init);
$("#restart").on("click", () => dispatchEvent(snakeEvent));


function gameloop () {
    moveSnake();
    if (compareCoords()) {
        addBodyPart();
        scene.remove(game.food.box);
        addFood();
    };
    checkForDeath();
};

function moveSnake () {
    let prev = "", x, y;
    game.snake.body.forEach((part, i) => {
        if (i === 0) {
            x = part.x;
            y = part.y;
            prev = part.d;
            switch (game.snake.d) {
                case "+x":
                    part.x += 1;
                    break;
                case "-x":
                    part.x -= 1;
                    break;
                case "+y":
                    part.y += 1;
                    break;
                case "-y":
                    part.y -= 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    part.x += 1;
                    break;
            };
            gsap.fromTo(
                part.box.position, 
                {x: x, y: y, duration: 0.1}, 
                {x: x + (part.x - x), y: y + (part.y - y), duration: 0.1}
            );
            part.d = game.snake.d;
        } else {
            x = part.x;
            y = part.y;
            let d = prev
            prev = part.d;
            part.d = d;
            switch (d) {
                case "+x":
                    part.x += 1;
                    break;
                case "-x":
                    part.x -= 1;
                    break;
                case "+y":
                    part.y += 1;
                    break;
                case "-y":
                    part.y -= 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    part.x += 1;
                    break;
            };
            gsap.fromTo(
                part.box.position, 
                {x: x, y: y, duration: 0.1}, 
                {x: x + (part.x - x), y: y + (part.y - y), duration: 0.1}
            );
        };
    });
};

function compareCoords () {
    let s = game.snake.body[0],
        f = game.food;
    if (s.x === f.x && s.y === f.y && s.z === f.z) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};

function addBodyPart () {
    let b = game.snake.body,
        l = b[b.length - 1],
        c = l.getCoords(),
        d = l.getDirection();
    setTimeout(() => {
        b.push(new CreateSnake(c[0], c[1], 1, d));
        b[b.length - 1].box.position.set(c[0], c[1], 0);
        scene.add(b[b.length - 1].box);
        game.snake.length++;
    }, 100);
};

function addFood () {
    game.food = new CreateFood();
    let f = game.food;
    f.box.position.x = f.x;
    f.box.position.y = f.y;
    scene.add(f.box);
};

function validFoodLocations () {
    let x, y;
    while (!(x > 0 && x < gamesize && notInSnakeX(x))) {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * gamesize);
    };
    while (!(y > 0 && y < gamesize && notInSnakeY(y))) {
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * gamesize);
    };
    return [x, y];
};

function notInSnakeX (x) {
    let res = true;
    game.snake.body.forEach(element => {
        if (element.x === x) {
            res = false;
        };
    });
    return res;
};

function notInSnakeY (y) {
    let res = true;
    game.snake.body.forEach(element => {
        if (element.y === y) {
            res = false;
        };
    });
    return res;
};

function keyDown (e) {
    let t, d = game.snake.d;
    switch(e.code) {
        case "KeyA":
            t = "-x";
            break;
        case "KeyW":
            t = "+y";
            break;
        case "KeyD":
            t = "+x";
            break;
        case "KeyS":
            t = "-y";
            break;
        default:
            d = d;
    };
    if (t !== undefined && !(t.charAt(1) === d.charAt(1) && t.charAt(0) !== d.charAt(0))) {
        game.snake.d = t;
    };
};

function animate () {
    if (game.running) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
};

function die () {
    game.snake = {
        body: [],
        length: 0,
        d: "+x"
    };
    game.food = {};
    game.running = false;
    clearInterval(game.gameloop);
    delete game.gameloop;
};

function checkForDeath () {
    let b = game.snake.body,
        h = b[0];
    if (h.x < 0 || h.x > gamesize || h.y < 0 || h.y > gamesize || checkForTouch(b, h)) {
        die();
    };
};

function checkForTouch (arr, v) {
    let res = false;
    arr.forEach((element, i) => {
        if (i !== 0 && element.x === v.x && element.y === v.y) {
            res = true;
        };
    });
    return res;
};
```

Extra information: I have tested it on Opera Gx and Edge. The crash happens when the snake has 31 "Body parts".

I have tried many things, for example splitting everything into different files or removing some renderer functions, but it didn't help.
I also tried to change the Mesh from THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() to THREE.MeshBasicMateria() and then I could get up to 41 snake parts. (In the jsfiddle I used NormalMaterial that anyone trying to recreate the error doesn't have to play to long.)
I have no idea what causes this and any help would be great.

---

### **EDIT**

As @Axiome answered, my problem was that the CPU sends the same mesh to the GPU every time. I watched a video about instanced rendering and learnt that the same meshes have to be calculated by the GPU every time, which is not the case with InstancedMesh. My question and problem have been solved, so I have marked the answer as accepted.
**BUT** I would like to point out to anyone who has a similar problem that Instanced Rendering and thus InstancedMesh is a huge effort afterwards and also generally involves some difficulties.
For anyone in need: [This video saved my life](https://youtu.be/dKg5H1OtDK8?si=ylgSwhTjOLQsVBma)

Comment: This question contains a lot of code but too few debugging details.  Consider improving both aspects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I see, and it could not be exhaustive.

For instance, you loop two times every time in every part of the body to check the X coordinate, and you loop again to check the Y coordinate, where you should loop one time on the body part and test each of the conditions you need to perform on the per-se body part.

Basically, you have let say X conditions to test. You do not loop on you 41 body parts and testing each one the condition in the same loop. You 41 times each X condition you would have. That is a waste of resources, because also the CPU must reload information from the memory everytime where you could have worked on every information available for a single load on a single object.

I would use also InstancedMesh for the body of the snake, no need to create an entire new geometry of a box, each time. You can reuse what is loaded on the GPU for the first box.

```js
function notInSnakeX (x) {
    let res = true;
    game.snake.body.forEach(element => {
        if (element.x === x) {
            res = false;
        };
    });
    return res;
};

function notInSnakeY (y) {
    let res = true;
    game.snake.body.forEach(element => {
        if (element.y === y) {
            res = false;
        };
    });
    return res;
};
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot.
Do you by any chance know how to properly work with a instanced Mesh. I am really overwhelmed by this subject.